# iOS 6 UIScrollview: Help My Taco App Keeps Crashing

Tags: ios, memory-management, uiscrollview, automatic-ref-counting

I have a UIScrollView full of tacos. 
I attached a pull-to-refresh handler to it via: https://github.com/samvermette/SVPullToRefresh

It extends  uiscrollview, and exposes this method:

```
[scrollview addInfiniteScrollingWithActionHandler:^{
    // Get me more tacos
}];
```

When InfiniteScrolling is triggered,  I clear the scrollview's subviews and data array(intentionally) and replace it with a new set.
It works great the first time. However, when I want to load more tacos it crashes.

I get:

```
-[SVInfiniteScrollingView retain]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x1e5db5d0
```

Not surprisingly, if I leave 1 subview left in my UIScrollview, everything works fine.

**Question:** How can I fix this?

I thought about declaring my properties with a strong pointer, like:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet tacoScroller *tacoScroller;
```

*But*, I worry about a retain cycle & it also doesn't work.

Any help would be appreciated, perhaps I'm missing something fundamental.

Edit:
I'm using ARC

Answer (score 1):

Use an UITableView to show your tacos, this way you will reuse views and avoid wasting memory. Also it is the easiest and most convenient way to show a list of things.

Comment: And you're on iOS6, so you can use the built in pull-to-refresh functionality without using third-party code.

Answer (score 0):

One simplest solution according to your description is simply add an empty & hidden subview inside the scrollview, i am sure it wont occupy much amount of memory.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are invoking the wrong method. Infinite scrolling is for other purposes.

You probably want to use

```
[scrollView addPullToRefreshWithActionHandler:^{ ... }];
```

Also, as others pointed out, you definitely should consider to use a `UITableView` to present your data, which seems to be very suitable for the task.